# QtRuby: loading HTML file into QTextEdit

Tags: ruby, qt4, qtextedit

How do I load a custom HTML-file into QTextEdit while in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple way.  Be sure to check the documentation, look for error conditions, and what-not.  Also, there might be a quicker way than reading it one line at a time.

```
QFile file( file_name );
QTextStream stream( &file );
QString string;
while( !stream.atEnd() )
{
    stream >> string;
    ui_textEdit->insertHtml( string );
}
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that this was tagged as ruby.  It shouldn't be too difficult to convert my c++ to the proper ruby equivalent.